# 'Execute' not performing command preceeded by 'run' in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In 1.12, I had the command:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ teleport @s ~ ~ ~
```

In a 'repeat' command block. This would freeze all players until I chose to unfreeze them. In 1.13, I assumed the adjustment to this syntax would be:

```
execute at @a run tp @s ~ ~ ~
```

In a 'repeat' command block. However, this does not work. To attempt to debug, I tried:

```
execute at @a run give @s stone 1
```

Still to no avail. I also tried replacing the selector in the run part:

```
 execute at @a run give @p stone 1
```

And nothing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the executor (only the command position), so `@s` is targeting nobody. You can execute the command as the player like this:

```
execute as @a at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~
```

In addition, relative teleports will no longer stop motion. Absolute teleports and teleports to entities still do though, so you could do:

```
execute as @a run tp @s @s
```

Note also that I've removed the `at @s`, since relative coordinates aren't being used anymore so it's no longer needed.

Comment: Does that not run the command as @a? What if @a doesn't have permission to use /tp?

Comment: Also, this does not have the same behaviour as the command I listed in 1.12. In 1.12, the command would freeze a player in the spot they were standing in at the time the command began execution. This does not do that

Comment: @Xav It doesn't use permission level of the player being executed as, it uses the permission level of the command block.

Comment: @Xav Ah true, relative TPs no longer stop motion. I've updated the answer with a command that should stop motion.